# How to find subscribers(or Followers) from FeedItem?

Tags: community, chatter, feeditem

I want to know how to find the subscriber of a FeedItem, so that I can mail him as new feed gets created.

I tried with FeedItem, EntitySubscription and one custom object's field. But failing to get the exact subscriber.

Thanks.!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the subscriber of a FeedItem. Can you be more specific? How does a person subscribe to a feed item? You can follow people, groups, or records -- that's what causes EntitySubscriptions to be created.

Comment: subscriber means the Follower of that Feed, btw I resolved that issue. Thanks!